After finding all combinations of 5 unique elements, I then want to find which combination appears the most times in a list of lists?
In python I used itertools combination to get all unique 5 combinations:
from itertools import combinations
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e", "f"]
combinations_of_5 = list(combinations(lst, 5))

I then have a list of lists that I've filtered to only include items from lst. I now need to count the most popular combination found in a list of lists.
lst_of_lsts = [
               ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"],
               ["e", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "c"],
               ["a", "b", "a", "d", "b", "a", "a"],
               ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d"],
               ["e", "d", "c", "b","a"]
              ]

I thought it would be fairly straight forwards but I've been struggling to find a reliable way to do this and ensure the results are accurate. My actual list of lists is much larger (a few million lists) and I'd like to know the top 10 most popular combinations found in the list of lists. My thought was to maybe use a sliding window technique and see if any of the combinations exist in there.
any help appreciated.
attempted solution provided:
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e"]

lst_of_lsts = [
               ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"],
               ["e", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "c"],
               ["a", "b", "a", "d", "b", "a", "a"],
               ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d"],
               ["e", "d", "c", "b","a"]
              ]

combinations_of_5 = set(combinations(lst, 5))

data = map(tuple, lst_of_lsts)
c = Counter(comb for comb in data if comb in combinations_of_5)
print(c.most_common(10))

this returns []

combinations_of_5 contains exactly one sequence, because there is only one way to choose five items from a pool of five items (order doesn't matter).

@JohnGordon you're totally right. The actual lst is 100 items I just put this up there quickly, updated thanks!

Then it would probably help to post code that better illustrates your actual need.

@user24714692 I expect the output to return most common combination found within list of lists then the number of times found. It seems trivial but for some reason kinda tough.

@user24714692 no because the combination pattern should be of only unique characters no duplicates. And max 5 for the pattern length.

@user24714692 the outputs should only be counting length five patterns. How are the actually combination patterns being checked? Before I used list(combinations(lst, 5)) to ensure I caught all possible unique 5 combinations.

Is there any relation in between lst_of_lsts and combinations_of_5? Or simply where is lst_of_lsts coming from?

@joelion2 Check Code 4? Is that it?

@user24714692 the relation is that combinations_of_5 is just all possible combinations, might be brute forcing it though. And my thought was iterate each possible combination of length 5 and check to see if it exists in the lst_of_lsts if so then add a counter to it. At the end find the most common combination. The new one seems a bit wonky and confusing to understand, sorry. The solution needs to be scalable, there are millions of lists.

"this returns []" - And what should it return?

First store the itertools generated combinations in a set for fast membership testing.
   combinations_of_5 = set(combinations(lst, 5))

Next filter your list into collections.Counter:
   data = map(tuple, lst_of_lsts)
   c = Counter(comb for comb in data if comb in combinations_of_5)
   print(c.most_common(10))

That said, I think you may actually be looking for permutations rather than combinations.

For this order doesn't matter, I simply want to count the number of times a patterns occurs somewhere in the list of lists. This is being run against a few million lists so I need it to be performant as possible. Each letter represents an action, I am trying to find the most common sequence of actions.

I also just attempted this solution but it returns me back []

You can simply use the Counter, as [Counter(l) for l in lst_of_lsts]:
Code 1
from collections import Counter

lst_of_lsts = [
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"],
    ["e", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "c"],
    ["a", "b", "a", "d", "b", "a", "a"],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d"],
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
]

counters = [Counter(l) for l in lst_of_lsts]
res = [counter.most_common(1)[0] for counter in counters]
print(counters)
print(res)



Prints
[Counter({'d': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'e': 1, 'a': 1}), Counter({'e': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}), Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}), Counter({'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1}), Counter({'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 'a': 1})]
[('d', 2), ('e', 2), ('a', 4), ('c', 2), ('e', 1)]


Code 2
from collections import Counter

lst_of_lsts = [
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"],
    ["e", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "c"],
    ["a", "b", "a", "d", "b", "a", "a"],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d"],
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
]

counter = Counter([tuple(sorted(l)) for l in lst_of_lsts])
print(counter.most_common(1)[0])


Prints
(('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e'), 1)


Code 3
from collections import Counter

lst_of_lsts = [
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"],
    ["e", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "c"],
    ["a", "b", "a", "d", "b", "a", "a"],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d"],
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
]

counter = Counter([tuple(sorted(set(l))) for l in lst_of_lsts])
print(counter)
print(counter.most_common(1)[0])

Prints
Counter({('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'): 3, ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e'): 1, ('a', 'b', 'd'): 1})
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), 3)


Code 4:
import string
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

lst = string.ascii_lowercase[0:6]
combinations_of_5 = tuple(combinations(lst, 5))
# print(combinations_of_5)

lst_of_lsts = [
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a", "c", "d", "b"],
    ["e", "b", "c", "a", "b", "e", "c"],
    ["a", "b", "a", "d", "b", "a", "a"],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d"],
    ["e", "d", "c", "b", "a"]
]

res = Counter([tuple(sorted(l)) for l in lst_of_lsts if len(l) == len(set(l)) and len(l) == 5])
print(res)



Prints
Counter({('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'): 1})


If I wanted to use permutations instead of combinations, would code 4 be dramatically different or would I simply swap out combination for permutation from itertools?

@joelion2 No, you just replace it with: tuple(permutations(lst, 5)). The problem is I don't really know what you're trying to do. lst_of_lsts  is defined by you manually and that's pretty much the core part of the Counter: Counter([tuple(sorted(l)) for l in lst_of_lsts if len(l) == len(set(l)) and len(l) == 5]). Just ask new questions, and clearly define the expected output, with these code.
